# Using `function.caller`

Tags: javascript

Two part question:

1. How to get `function.caller` from an object method.
2. How to use that value to actually *call* the function.

Example:

```
foo = {
    bar: function() {console.log(bar.caller);}
}
```

`>> SyntaxError: function statement requires a name`

Example 2:

`[bar.caller]();` ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In general, `this` will be the value of the object that invoked the method, but there are some caveats. If the invocation was done as `foo.bar()`, then `this` will be the `foo` object.

Comment: As to the error, that appears to be coming from elsewhere.

Comment: @squint - nope, `function.caller` does not work with anonymous functions, which is essentially what a method declaration is. And the call is essentially a 'getter' called from another object. `this` won't work in my case.

Comment: I didn't say anything about `function.caller`. What you're asking is somewhat unclear. If you're saying you want the function, why not just give it a name? Why must it be anonymous? Can you clarify what value you hope to get?

Comment: That error comes about when you use invalid function declaration syntax; one without a name. The only function you show is as an expression, not a declaration, so it wouldn't produce the error.

Comment: @squint - The example declares a method `bar` on the object `foo` - no?

Comment: Yes, it does. I just found docs for [this non-standard feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller), so maybe that's what you're referring to. If so, you would either need to get reference to the current function via the object property: `foo.bar.caller`, or you can give the function a name and use that directly: `var foo = { bar: function bar() { console.log(bar.caller) } };`

Comment: i don't know what you are trying to achieve, but `function.caller` (and so `arguments.caller` and `arguments.callee` are) are [obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller) and not meant to be used in production code.

Comment: @NonPolynomial - `arguments.caller` is depracated, `function.caller` is its replacement.

Comment: @allnodcoms its a non-standard feature, which you should avoid in production code.
`This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.`

Comment: @allnodcoms: What is your source for the suggestion that `function.caller` is a replacement for `arguments.caller`?

Comment: @squint - >This property replaces the obsolete arguments.caller property of the arguments object.
See NonPolynomial's MDN (obsolete) link above.

Comment: Yes, I saw that sentence below the box telling you to not use it. In any case, if you wish to use non-standard features, that's up to you. You have 3 solutions on this page that get you to that property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the caller (if it exist) use this:

```
var caller = arguments.callee.caller;
```

To use it you have to check if it exist first like this:

```
if(caller)
    caller();
```

**EXAMPLE:**

```js
function foo(param){
  if(param == 5) return console.log(param);
  
  var caller = arguments.callee.caller;
  if(caller)
    caller(param + 1);
}

function bar(param){
  foo(param);
}

foo(3); // won't log anything (no caller and param != 5)

bar(3); // will cause a recursion until param == 5 then logs it.
```

Comment: But the `arguments` object is depracated.

Comment: @allnodcoms: The `arguments` object is not deprecated.

Comment: @allnodcoms `arguments` is not deprecated. Proof??

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir [try this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller)

Comment: @allnodcoms this sais `function.caller` is deprecated not `arguments` is deprecated. Take a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir - Nearly. That link says `arguments.caller` is depracated.

Comment: @allnodcoms `arguments.caller` is deprecated but `arguments.callee` isn't and that what I'm using. (all there is about `argument.calle` is that it may not work in ECMA strict mode which is out of our concern right now)

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir - You're right. `caller` is there in the function `__proto__`, but is always (in my tests) `null`. `arguments.callee.caller` returns the function object of the method that called it. Sorry for any arguments (excuse the deliberate pun!), I've marked this as the correct answer to the question. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You shouldn't use [`arguments.callee`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee#Description), its [removed from `strict mode`](Why was arguments.callee removed from ES5 strict mode?). and [arguments.caller](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/caller#Browser_compatibility) is not supported! using this is just bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the code you posted is that `bar` doesn't mean anything inside that anonymous function. The name "bar" is a property name of the object assigned to `foo`. Thus this works fine:

```
var foo = {
  bar: function() {
    console.log("Caller is: " + foo.bar.caller);
  }
};

function x() {
  foo.bar();
}

x();
```

The function doesn't need a name; that's irrelevant. In order to get to the `caller` property you need a reference to the function, and that can come from anywhere. This would therefore also work:

```
var foo = {
  bar: function() {
    console.log("Caller is: " + this.bar.caller);
  }
};

function x() {
  foo.bar();
}

x();
```

because when that function is invoked as `foo.bar()` the value of `this` will be the "foo" object.

Comment: The lack of a function name becomes very relevant the moment `foo` gets reassigned or `this` turns out to be an unexpected value.

Comment: @squint agreed; I would in fact not write code that way, and might do something like create the "foo" object in a closure or something to guarantee access to the object from the function. (In a larger sense, I'm not sure I've ever really wanted `function.caller`, though I suppose in some debugging instances it might be useful.)

Comment: Yep, it would be hard to convince me that using the `.caller` for any other purpose would be the best approach, but who knows I guess. Maybe debugging, but a breakpoint with a visual on the call stack sure seems nicer to me.

Comment: @Pointy - Nailed it... Just needed to increase the specificity. Thanks matey.
And while you're on a roll - calling the 'caller'? ;o)

Comment: @allnodcoms `foo.bar.caller()` would call the caller function